# Features of CoreMotion in WatchOS3

Tags: swift, apple-watch, core-motion

I'm working on App's Watch to track the user moving the watch, I searched on this feature and they recommended to use CoreMotion,

My questions are:

1- How to use CoreMotion in Apple Watch to record CoreMotion data (historical info)?

2- does the CoreMotion work even if the App is in the background or killed?

Thanks for your helping,

Comment: 1. This example app by Apple shows how to use CoreMotion: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SwingWatch/Introduction/Intro.html
2. CoreMotion works when the app is in the background as long as it remains in "Workout" mode

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! you made my day actually :) but what did you mean by "Workout" mode? and if the app is killed did the coreMotion works? thanks again @Paolo

Comment: Workout mode is activated by starting a session with `HKHealthStore` and you can tell it's activated by the little green running icon at the top of the clock watch face (you can try this with the regular workouts app). Live CoreMotion updates won't work when the app is killed but you can still retrieve data that was recorded by the Watch itself while the app was not active (e.g. the data you see in the Health app)

Comment: @Paolo oh thanks, but did you mean that I can't use CoreMotion without HealthKit if I want to track user motion?  
sorry for too many questions, but I'm very new watch developer

Comment: @Paolo and for Kill App state, can the HealthKit retrieve the motion of the user?
if yes why do I need to use CoreMotion? 
Thanks again